# RxJava v1 to v2

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to learn RxJava 2 but since yesterday afternoon I'm having a bad time trying to translate from v1 to v2 of the RxJava library... I came across this function that I could use for something I'm doing to help me understand the whole Reactive-Programming paradigm.

```
List<Integer> emitList = ...;
Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.from(emitList);

observable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .parallel((a) -> {
            return a
            .filter((i) -> {
                return i % 2 == 0;
            })
            .doOnNext((xx) -> {
                System.out.println("parallel thread in: " + ThreadUtils.currentThreadName());
                System.out.println("parallel: " + xx);
                ThreadUtils.sleep(10);
                System.out.println("parallel thread out: " + ThreadUtils.currentThreadName());
            });
        },
        Schedulers.io()
        )
        .subscribe(
                (i) -> {
                    System.out.println("onNext thread entr: " + ThreadUtils.currentThreadName());
                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println("onNext thread exit: " + ThreadUtils.currentThreadName());
                },
                (t) -> {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                },
                () -> {
                    System.out.println("onCompleted()");
                }
        );
```

And the farthest I've got is this:

```
Observable<Integer> observable = ....
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .doOnNext(i -> {
          System.out.println("parallel thread in: " + threadName());
          System.out.println("parallel: " + i);
          Thread.sleep(10);
        })
        .subscribe(
                number -> System.out.println(threadName() + ": " + number),
                throwable -> System.err.println(threadName() + ": " + throwable.toString()),
                () -> System.out.println(threadName() + ": Completed!")

        );
```

I know there's a lot wrong with what I'm doing.. for starters the filtering and doOnNext its inside of the parallel clause, whereas in my "approach" its outside, and who knows what else.
I trying going through the tests on the RxJava repo, but I couldn't identify any that would be similar to this. I looked at the Flowable and ParallelFlowable but they are waaaaay different to the point I can't find how to achieve the parallelism on my version... which doesn't print a thing btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel processing in RxJava 2 is tied to `Flowable` and uses the same fluent API design as the `Observable`:

```
Flowable<Integer> f = ....
f.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .parallel()                          // <---------------------------------
    .runOn(Schedulers.computation())     // <---------------------------------
    .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
    .doOnNext(i -> {
      System.out.println("parallel thread in: " + threadName());
      System.out.println("parallel: " + i);
      Thread.sleep(10);
    })
    .sequential()                        // <---------------------------------
    .subscribe(
            number -> System.out.println(threadName() + ": " + number),
            throwable -> System.err.println(threadName() + ": " + throwable.toString()),
            () -> System.out.println(threadName() + ": Completed!")
    );

    Thread.sleep(10000);
```